# My computer is not shutting down due to Redis

Tags: redis, shutdown

I recently reinstalled Redis on my Computer.After this my computer is not shutting down.It says "Waiting for Redis to shut down". Earlier redis used to restart with all updated key values when I switch on my computer, but it's continuously running now. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

use the command `redis quit`

https://redis.io/commands/quit

Assuming that you are using Linux Or OSX you can use the command `top`in the terminal to find the PID

Once you've found this, type in `kill` followed by the PID